# AjaxControlToolkit's AsyncFileUpload misbehaving when deployed online

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ajaxcontroltoolkit

In case it matters, the following is inside a toolkit popup, which has an update panel in it.

```
<p>
    <asp:Label Text="Picture" runat="server" Width="75"></asp:Label>
    <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="MediaPicture" runat="server" Width="200"
        OnClientUploadStarted="BlockSubmits" ClientIDMode="AutoID"
        OnClientUploadError="UnblockSubmits" PersistFile="true"
        OnClientUploadComplete="UnblockSubmits" 
    />
</p>
```

The javascript functions just block / release a submit button, to prevent problems during uploads.

This works fine on localhost, but when deployed online on a GoDaddy server, I can't seem to upload files over a few KB, even when locally I could upload bigger files (~2MB)...

I can't seem to find the reason for this behavior, could it be on the IIS? I read something about the app pool clearing before the upload could complete, could this be happening?

Btw, just in case, server-side I just take the picture out of this control

```
byte[] picture = MediaPicture.FileBytes ?? (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaID) ? null : Media.SelectByID(int.Parse(mediaID)).GetPicture());
```

There's some extra logic in there about whether I'm in edit mode or not, and if the current record has a picture, I'll take that over no picture,

And then I store it on the database.

any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

thanks!

Comment: Is there any error you get in the onclientuploaderror event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, the problem is caused by the AsyncFileUpload being located inside the updatepanel, thereby having the file upload happen during a postback...

This [blog post has a decent explanation of why](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/03/30/why-don-t-file-uploads-work-during-async-postbacks.aspx).

As for why it works locally, if it is the problem as explained above, it's because of the way the browser handles "local" from "internet" domains.

Comment: The AsyncUpload is a modified version of the common file Upload. Its suppose to work within a update panel making assync calls to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The Assync upload of the ajax toolkit still has to have a post with the maximum request size of ASP.NET.

This max size is setted in the web.config of your application AND inside IIS. Since you are using a third party provider... try to fiddle with the web.config in the section

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960"/>
```

If this won't help you out, check out the SWFUpload control... saved my skin a couple of times.

Regards,

Comment: Can you ask to your provider the maximum request size in IIS?

Comment: Godaddy has an info page about this: http://community.godaddy.com/library/uploading-large-files-to-iis-and-asp-net/ There is a different config setting for IIS7. Though the default should still be 4 meg. I would try making a simple upload form (not using AjaxControlToolkit, just use FileUpload control) to make sure the problem is the upload size vs. something more insidious related to the control or the UpdatePanel

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use different IIS versions in your development environment and in the the production server (in this case Go Daddy).Can you verify and let me know the exact IIS versions so that I can provide you a better solution? Cause IIS 7.0 has a slightly different configuration than IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem, but including the website in the "Local Intranet" zone in IE the security setting was a workaround.

**However, I updated the Ajax Control Toolkit and the problem was completely solved. There is no more need to mess with the security setting.**